# Dataverse user error while requesting data through the API

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

I'm trying to request data from the Dataverse through the API.

I did the following:

1. I created an application in Azure with the respective API permissions and generated a secret.
2. Using OAuth, I got the bearer token in order to authorize my requests using the client secret `grant_type=client_credentials`.
3. When I make a request I get the following error, *"The user is not a member of the organization."*.

I'm not sure how to add the "Azure App user" to the environment because there is none.

Also, I can successfully make the request if I get the bearer token using user/password, `grant_type=password`, where this user is in the power apps environment.

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found the answer through this post, [I am not able to connect to dataverse API through Logic Apps - Error: "The user is not a member of the organization."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71498799/9090849)

We need to add the created azure application in the `Application Users` menu (`Enviorment -> Settings -> Users + permissions -> Application Users`)

Thank you!